# Index on a table not being used all the time

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-performance

I am looking for some insight into how indices on MySQL tables work as I am encountering some issues that I don't understand.

Let's start with the table I am working with:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE channeldata\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: channeldata
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `channeldata` (
  `channel_id` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `station_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `reading` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `average` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `location_lat` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `location_lon` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `location_alt` double(8,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
  `quality` smallint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`channel_id`,`station_id`,`time`),
  KEY `composite3` (`station_id`,`channel_id`,`quality`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `composite` (`channel_id`,`station_id`,`time`,`quality`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (YEAR(time))
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2001) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2002) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2003) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2004) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (2005) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (2006) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (2007) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (2008) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (2009) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (2010) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (2011) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN (2012) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN (2013) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p13 VALUES LESS THAN (2014) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p14 VALUES LESS THAN (2015) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p15 VALUES LESS THAN (2016) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p16 VALUES LESS THAN (2017) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p17 VALUES LESS THAN (2018) ENGINE = MyISAM) */
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am running queries to select data in August/Sept/Oct of 2017. The 'readings' are spread out evenly across the day and are always on a 10 minute boundary (i.e. 10:10:00, 10:20:00, 10:30:00 etc) The number of 'readings' per day is fairly consistent at 15.000 from May 2017 onwards. In total the P17 partition has just over 3 million readings.

The query I would like some help with looks like this:

```
SELECT 
        ROUND(`a`.`average`,2) `average`,
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`a`.`time`) * 1000 time,
        `a`.`station_id`
    FROM
        `argus`.`channeldata` PARTITION (p17) `a` 
    WHERE
        ((`a`.`station_id` = '3002' AND a.channel_id = '1') OR (`a`.`station_id` = '3004' AND a.channel_id = '1') OR [...] OR (`a`.`station_id` = '5052' AND a.channel_id = '1')) AND `a`.`time` BETWEEN "2017-08-17 00:00:00" AND "2017-10-13 23:59:59"  AND `a`.`quality` IN('1') ORDER BY `a`.`time` ASC;
```

Here's that query formatted to show the `WHERE` conditions clearly.

```
SELECT 
        ROUND(`a`.`average`,2) `average`,
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`a`.`time`) * 1000 time,
        `a`.`station_id`
    FROM
        `argus`.`channeldata` PARTITION (p17) `a` 
    WHERE
        (     (`a`.`station_id` = '3002' AND a.channel_id = '1') 
           OR (`a`.`station_id` = '3004' AND a.channel_id = '1')
           OR [...]
           OR (`a`.`station_id` = '5052' AND a.channel_id = '1'))
     AND `a`.`time` BETWEEN "2017-08-17 00:00:00" AND "2017-10-13 23:59:59"  
     AND `a`.`quality` IN('1')
   ORDER BY `a`.`time` ASC;
```

Just to get some metrics I started to select readings from a 4 week, 5 week etc interval. The execution time for these queries to complete is around the 4 - 5 second mark, increasing slightly the more days I add to the interval. However, all of a sudden there is a jump in execution time. Adding just one day to the 'BETWEEN' interval almost quadruples the execution time to nearly 20 seconds.

I ran the before & after query within explain and the results are something I don't understand.

With the interval being `BETWEEN "2017-08-18 00:00:00" AND "2017-10-13 23:59:59"` EXPLAIN looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | range | PRIMARY,composite3,composite | PRIMARY | 12      | NULL | 542026 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Increasing this by one day to `BETWEEN "2017-08-17 00:00:00" AND "2017-10-13 23:59:59"` looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL  | PRIMARY,composite3,composite | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 3056618 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What is going on there? Why is it suddenly not able to use a primary key / index and instead of searching a subset of rows it has to search the entire 3 million for that partition. On a sidenote, the exact location of the interval is not important. I can recreate this problem by moving the interval a month earlier as well.

If it helps, the columns returned before the 'jump' in execution time is 525644 and the number when I add 1 extra day is 535004.

Comment: What percentage of the data has `quality=1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter criteria are:

1. an explicit partition choice
2. an equality match on `quality`
3. a range scan on `time`
4. a bundle of pairwise matches on `station_id` and `channel_id` ored together.

An index to handle criteria 2 and 3 is what you need.  Put the equality-match column first in your index, then the range-scan column, then round out the index with the other columns you need for the query to get a [covering index](http://www.unofficialmysqlguide.com/covering-indexes.html).

That index is  `(quality, time, station_id, channel_id, average)`

Why does it work?  The query planner can jump immediately to the first eligible row of the index, because it knows both `quality` and the start `time` required. It can then scan the index sequentially doing the pairwise matches and retrieving the `average` column. MySQL can satisfy the entire query from the index, which saves a lot of jumping back to the table to fetch information, and so speeds it up.

You already have an index on `(channel_id,station_id,time,quality)`. You may want to drop that index when you create your new one, because it looks like it's serving a similar purpose.

Why does the query planner sometimes use an index and sometimes not? It depends on a lot of things, primarly the query planner's estimation about whether it will have to do less work using the index or just scanning the table. Indexes and columns contain estimates of cardinality -- the number of different values in the data item. Those cardinality numbers are estimates, and they're sometimes quite inaccurate.  You have partitions: that may induce the query planner to restrict its choices somehow. The fallback when the query planner can't figure out what to do is what you got: a full table scan.

The indexes mentioned in your question already required quite a bit of laborious index scanning to satisfy the query; I guess the query planner switched to a full table scan strategy when you changed the datestamp range.   This is a hassle for people operating DBMS-based software: as an application grows, sometimes the query planner suddenly flips to a new and less efficient plan. You need to stay on top of sudden performance changes and add indexes.

Pro tip: asking *why* about query planner choices is generally a fruitless enterprise compared to building a better index. (Unless your development job is working on the query planner.)

I suggested a five-column index. Your query uses four columns for filtering, and then uses the last column to present results. Including all five columns in the index means MySQL doesn't have to return to the individual rows found by the index in the main table. It can satisfy the query from the index alone, meaning it can read the index sequentially from mass storage. On a traditional spinning hard drive, that means the read heads don't have to go tick-tock-tick-tock back and forth from index to table to index to satisfy the query. It's far faster. It's called a [covering index](http://www.unofficialmysqlguide.com/covering-indexes.html).

Pro tip:  Using `BETWEEN` for datestamp ranges is a mistake. Instead of using

```
  WHERE time BETWEEN '2017-08-17 00:00:00' AND '2017-10-13 23:59:59'
```

use this. It's more precise on the end of the range. And it still gets range scanned.

```
  WHERE time >= '2017-08-17' 
    AND time <  '2017-10-13' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: Works a charm, thx very much. I would love to understand why MySQL decided to stop using the existing index in my original problem though. I did read somewhere that when the rows it needs to examine is about 30% of the total it suddenly stops using an index, but I don't know if this is true. And also, why is average added to the index when it isn't being used in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1):

The optimizer has two ways to perform an indexed query over a range:

Option 1, Use the index:

1. Reach into the index at the start of the items.
2. Scan forward until the end of the range.  Filter out any rows that don't match other `WHERE` criteria.
3. For each item reach over into the data to get the other columns needed.  This is a random read into disk -- possibly not cached, etc.

Option 2, Ignore the index and scan the data.

1. Scan all rows in the data, ignoring any that don't match the `WHERE` criteria.

The cutoff between doing one method and doing the other depends on a lot of statistics, etc.  It is often between 10% and 30% of the table.  You noted a big jump at the boundary; this is because the statistics are not 'perfect'.  That jump can be for the better or for the worse.

A side note.  Once you have Ollie's better index, the partitioning buys you no performance.  In fact it probably slows down the query.

`DOUBLE` (8 bytes) for lat/lng/alt is overkill.  See [*my representation choices*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices).

`DOUBLE(8,3)` (still 8 bytes) is even worse; never use `(m,n)` on `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.

The average of averages is mathematically incorrect.  Consider keeping a sum and a count, then computing `SUM(sum)/SUM(count)` to get a proper `AVG`.

Want to get weekly results 10 times as fast?  Build and maintain counts and sums daily in a summary table.  That would shrink the data by 1/144.  Then report by summing the sums, etc.  A [*discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) on Summary Tables.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately table & retrieval are not mine. The interval that is used is arbitrary, it can be 2 days or it can be 3 months. The average is actually calculated upon data insertion (it is the average of the last X readings including the current one) and is correct - they just needed it rounded to 2 decimals I guess. Are you sure partitioning doesn't make any difference? The example quoted is on a test machine, on the live server we have millions of readings a year going back 2 decades (if the interval is on a partition boundary I will obviously account for that).